# Partiton mysql table by column timestamp

Tags: mysql, partition, database-partitioning

I am trying to partition my table MySQL innoDB. Right now there are approximately 2 million rows in the location table (and growing always) rows of history data. I must perodicly delete the dataset old by year
I use MySQL 5.7.22 Community Server.

```
CREATE TABLE `geo_data` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID_DISP` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SYS_TIMESTAMP` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATA_TIMESTAMP` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `X` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Y` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `SPEED` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HEADING` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID_DATA_TYPE` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PROCESSED` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ALTITUDE` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID_UNIT` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID_DRIVER` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `part_id` (`ID`,`DATA_TIMESTAMP`,`ID_DISP`),
  KEY `Index_idDisp_dataTS_type` (`ID_DISP`,`DATA_TIMESTAMP`,`ID_DATA_TYPE`),
  KEY `Index_idDisp_dataTS` (`ID_DISP`,`DATA_TIMESTAMP`),
  KEY `Index_TS` (`DATA_TIMESTAMP`),
  KEY `idx_sysTS_idDisp` (`ID_DISP`,`SYS_TIMESTAMP`),
  KEY `idx_clab_geo_data_ID_UNIT_DATA_TIMESTAMP_ID_DATA_TYPE` (`ID_UNIT`,`DATA_TIMESTAMP`,`ID_DATA_TYPE`),
  KEY `idx_idUnit_dataTS` (`ID_UNIT`,`DATA_TIMESTAMP`),
  KEY `idx_clab_geo_data_ID_DRIVER_DATA_TIMESTAMP_ID_DATA_TYPE` (`ID_DRIVER`,`DATA_TIMESTAMP`,`ID_DATA_TYPE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=584390 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have to partition by `DATA_TIMESTAMP` (format timestamp date gps).

```
ALTER TABLE geo_data
PARTITION BY RANGE (year(from_unixtime(data_timestamp)))
(
   PARTITION p2018 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018'),
   PARTITION p2019 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019'),
   PARTITION pmax VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

> Error Code: 1697. VALUES value for partition 'p2018' must have type INT

How can I do?

I would like to add later a subpartion range by ID_DISP. How can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Since `data_timestamp` was actually a `BIGINT`, you are not permitted to use date functions.  It seemed there were two errors, and this probably fixes them:

```
ALTER TABLE geo_data
PARTITION BY RANGE (data_timestamp)
(
   PARTITION p2018 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-01-01') * 1000),
   PARTITION p2019 VALUES LESS THAN (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2019-01-01') * 1000),
   PARTITION pmax VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

I am assuming your `data_timestamp` is really milliseconds, a la Java?  If not, the decide what to do with the `* 1000`.

`SUBPARTITIONs` are useless; don't bother with them.  If you really want to partition by Month or Quarter, then simply do it at the `PARTITION` level.

Recommendation:  Don't have more than about 50 partitions.

How many "drivers" do you have?  I suspect you do not have trillions.  So, don't blindly use `BIGINT` for ids.  Each takes 8 bytes.  `SMALLINT UNSIGNED`, for example, would take only 2 bytes and allow 64K drivers (etc).

If `X` and `Y` are latitude and longitude, it might be clearer to name them such.  [*Here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices) are what datatype to use instead of the 8-byte `DOUBLE`, depending on the resolution you have (and need).  4-byte `FLOATs` are probably good enough for vehicles.

The table has several redundant indexes; toss them.  Also, note that when you have `INDEX(a,b,c)`, it is redundant to also have `INDEX(a,b)`.

See also my [*discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) on Partitioning, especially related to time-series, such as yours.

Hmmm... I wonder if the 63 bits of precision for `SPEED` will let you record them when they go at the speed of light?

Another point:  Don't create `p2019` until just before the start of 2019.  You have `pmax` in case you goof and fail to add that partition in time.  And the `REORGANIZE PARTITION` mentioned in my discussion covers how to recover from such a goof.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Seems you cannot use `from_unixtime` in a `PARTITION BY RANGE` query because hash partitions must be based on an integer expression. More info [see this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50760/how-to-partition-a-table-by-timestamp-where-data-from-every-ith-day-goes-to-pa)

<strike>Its expecting an `INT` not a `STRING` (as per the error message), so try :</strike>

```
ALTER TABLE geo_data
PARTITION BY RANGE (year(from_unixtime(data_timestamp)))
(
   PARTITION p2018 VALUES LESS THAN (2018),
   PARTITION p2019 VALUES LESS THAN (2019),
   PARTITION pmax VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

Here I have specified the year in the partition values as an int ie 2018 / 2019, and not strings as in '2018' / '2019'

Comment: Error Code: 1564. This partition function is not allowed

Comment: See this answer -> https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50760/how-to-partition-a-table-by-timestamp-where-data-from-every-ith-day-goes-to-pa

Comment: it's interesting, but I should partition by year with partition range, no by hash